# How do I scale an object in only one direction?

Tags: after-effects

I am animating a volume meter, and have done the "tricky bit" of getting the volume value.

Now I want to apply the volume value to a mask , so that as the music moves, the mask is exposed in time to the beat.

I have tried two ways, the first by scaling the mask. However, I can't get it to scale in one direction only (i.e. it scales around a center point.) Even if I move the pan anchor it still doesn't pin the base of the shape.

The other way I tried was using a linear wipe. However, this was no good either, as the whole wipe effect is completed at 38% (i.e. if I move the slider the object vanishes totally at 38%, not 100% as I would expect.)

Is there a better way to do this?

Seems simple, but has me stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Set the *Anchor Point* to the **bottom** of the asset by using the *Anchor Point* tool (<kbd>Y</kbd>)

   [image] *Tool icon in CC versions*

   [image] *Tool icon in versions pre CC*

   [image]
2. Disable **proportional scaling** of that layer [image] and set the desired keyframes

**Demo in AE 22.0.0**

[image]

**Notes**

- The shape also can be used as **track matte**, just set the layer below to `Alpha`.
- *Consider* to add a **slider control**
- As alternative you could use a trim path on a shape layer as track matte, see this answer: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49643/how-to-use-after-effects-trim-path-with-an-illustrator-path/49975#49975

Comment: This doesn't work on v.17.1.1, apparently.

Comment: Still works the same way in AE 22.0.0 @LeeDean See the edit.